# C: generate array with random numbers in range (allwowing duplicates)

Tags: c, arrays, random

I want to write a C function that gets: a seed, int n (the number of random ints to generate), and upper limit (the max allowed number).

I came so far as to have somthing like this:

```
// I need a function definition here
// I forgot how to allocate the int array ... somehting with 'sizeof'?
srand(time(NULL));   //seed for rand    
for(i = 0; i < length; i++)
        array[i] = rand()%upperLimit;
return array;
```

Then I probably need those header files:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
```

Comment: Question is .... ?

Comment: Looks like you are on the right track. If you ever have questions about what headers are required by any standard C function, just `man functionname` and look at the top -- it tells you. (wonder what `time` needs??) Also, if by *range* your prof means `1 - upperlimit`, then you need `rand() % upperlimit + 1` (as `rand() % number` returns values in the range of `0 - (number - 1)`)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need    `#include <time.h>` for the `time` function.
  This is simple program matching your description with comments in the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int *
alocate (unsigned int n)
{
  return malloc (n * sizeof (int)); // allocate memory block for n numbers and return int pointer to it 
}

int *
generate_block_with_random_numbers (unsigned int n, int upper_limit)
{
//  function  `int *generate_block_with_random_numbers(unsigned int n, int upper_limit)` 
//  gets a positive integer n as an argument 
//  reserves the n block of int variables in memory 
//  fills this block with random values 
//  returns a pointer to the beginning of the reserved block. 

  srand (time (NULL));      //  seed generator

 int *array = alocate (n);  // note: array pointer always points to the beginning of the allocated memory  

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
      // you can index the array moving to its next element via [i] 
      array[i] = rand () % (upper_limit+1); // 
    }

  return array;
}


int
main ()
{

  unsigned int n = 5;
  unsigned int upperL = 5;

  int *block = generate_block_with_random_numbers (n, upperL);

  // Display the data contained in the returned block:
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
      printf ("%d\n", block[i]);    // print it
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
5
0
2
3
3
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Really! Was was expecting a million downvotes but instead you help. Love it!